# Draw box with colored background and linebreaks which adjusts to the text width?

Tags: color, boxes

I want to draw labels on a photograph. The labels will only contain 1..3 words, and sometimes there shall be a linebreak, e. g.

```
Big House \newline
(empty)
```

Is it possible to create a box which draws a white rectangle below this text and which adapts to the width of the text?

I could use `\colorbox{white}{Big House \newline (empty)}`, but it does not allow the linebreak.

If I use a `\parbox{}`, I have to define the width by hand.

Is there a box with a colored background, which can itself adapt its width to the longest text and contain linebreaks or paragraphs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the `varwidth` environment provided by the homonymous package; this environment is an analogue of `minipage`, but its resulting width is the natural width of its contents. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\MyCBox[1]{%
  \colorbox{red!60}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}#1\end{varwidth}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\MyCBox{Big House\\ (empty)}

\noindent\MyCBox{Big House and some more text\\ (empty)}

\noindent\MyCBox{Big\\ (empty)}

\noindent\MyCBox{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\newcommand\MyCBox[1]{% \colorbox{red!60}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}#1\end{varwidth}}}` While compiling we are getting the error as `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \dimexpr ` Please suggest me how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 4):

```
\newcommand{\overbox}[2][l]{%
  \colorbox{white}{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%
}

\overbox{Big House \\ (empty)}
```

One can also say

```
\overbox[c]{Big House \\ (empty)}
```

to get lines centered with respect to one another.

Example

[image]

Comment: You can also use `{@{}c@{}}` as the argument to `tabular` if you prefer centered lines. But see the edited answer for a slightly different approach.